# Logo in header changes with each Owl Carousel slide

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow, owl-carousel

I have Owl Carousel slideshow in my page which contains four pictures and each slide covers the whole screen. The first picture in the slideshow is mostly blue, however the remaining pictures are mostly white.

I have two logo pictures which are in the header positioned left upper corner. One logo image is white, and second one is black. I have included only white logo in the code below.

HTML code for both header and Owl Carousel slideshow.

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <h1 class="logo">
        <a class="" href="/main"><img src="images/white_logo.png"></a>
    </h1>
</div>

<section class="visual">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="item visual1">
            <div class="textbox">
                <div class="text">
                    <span>Text for slide 1! Background picture is mostly blue.</span>
                </div>   
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item visual2">
            <div class="textbox">
                <div class="text">
                    <span>Text for slide 2! Background picture is mostly white.</span>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item visual3">
            <div class="textbox">
                <div class="text">
                    <span>Text for slide 3! Background picture is mostly white.</span>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item visual4">
            <div class="textbox">
                <div class="text">
                    <span>Text for slide 4! Background picture is mostly white.</span>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then additonally, the script for Owl Carousel is as it follows:

```
$('.visual .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 0,
    nav: true,
    center: true,
    // autoplay:true,
    // autoplayTimeout:3000,
    // autoplayHoverPause:true,
    responsive: {
       0: {
           items: 1
          }
        },
        onInitialized: function() {
            repositionObj();
        },
        onResized: function() {
            repositionObj();
        }
    });
```

And, lastly CSS is:

```
.visual1 {
    background: url(../images/bluepicture.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover; 
}

.visual2 {
    background: url(../images/whitepicture01.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover; 
}

.visual3 {
    background: url(../images/whitepicture02.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover; 
}

.visual4 {
    background: url(../images/whitepicture04.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

For now, with this current code I have four pictures (one blue picture and three white ones), but only one logo image (white_logo.png) displaying for each picture in slide. White logo image suits fine at first since the first picture in Owl Carousel covering the whole screen is blue.

However, the next three images in Owl Carousel are mostly white so white logo image seems to be disappeared. For this matter, I have created another version of this logo which is colored in black. Let's call it (black_logo.png)

How can I display black logo in the header for only the pictures in Owl Carousel slideshows which are white, but white logo only for a blue picture?

So to speak:

- white_logo.png & bluepicture.png
- black_logo.png & whitepicture01.png
- black_logo.png & whitepicture02.png
- black_logo.png & whitepicture03.png